# Find integer numbers $x,y>1$ such that $x|3^y+1$ and $y|3^x+1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find all integer numbers $x,y>1$ such that $x|3^y+1$ and $y|3^x+1$. 
I tried to use $\text{ord}$ but still no clue.

Comment: $x=y=2$, for example. Or $x=5, y=2$...

Comment: Yes, I know that. But do you have any idea to solve this problem ?

Comment: I think that the first thing to do to solve this question is to assume that $x=y$ and solve the equation.

Comment: Essentially you have to figure out the pattern for the divisors of $3^n + 1$ in relation to $n$.

For one thing, $3^n + 1$ *must* be even. So what if $x = 2$? Then for $x|(3^y + 1)$ to hold true $y$ can be any integer whatsoever. But $y|(3^x + 1)$ limits our choices of $y$ to 10's four divisors: 1, 2, 5, 10.

What about $x = 3$? That won't work at all. Both $x$ and $y$ have to be coprime to 3. So we move on to $x = 4$. Then $y$ must be odd, since the powers of 3 modulo 4 are 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, ... But 82 is not divisible by 4, so nothing can work for $y$.