# Primes $p$ such that $ord_p(3)$ is a power of $2$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, finite-fields

I'm trying to solve this [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168793/find-integer-numbers-x-y1-such-that-x3y1-and-y3x1), and i need to find all primes $p$ for which $ord_p(3)$ is a power of $2$.

If such primes exist then they are of the form $p=2^km+1$ with $k\geq1$ and $m$ an odd integer, because $ord_p(3)$ is a power of $2$ we can assert that $p+1\leq 3^{2^k}$ which affirms that there is no such primes if $3^{2^k}\leq p$, numerically I find only fermat primes.

> **Question** Can we find all odd primes $p$ such that $ard_p(3)$ is a power of $2$

Comment: Well, by Fermat's little theorem, $2^k = ord_p(3) \; | \; \phi(p) = p-1$, so in general the primes have the form $p=2^km+1$. So we check over $m$ and $k$ I guess.

Comment: But in the case where $2^k\leq log(p)$ there is no such primes such that $ord_p(2)=2^t$ because $3^{2^k}$ will never be greater than $p$

Comment: Well in that case we'd have roughly $2^k \leq k \log(2) + \log(m)$, so $m$ would be a very large number.

Comment: But a lot of primes have $m$ very large, and i made some calculation i did not find any other primes other then Fermat'primes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primes $p$ with the property that $\operatorname{ord}_p(3)=2^k$ are surely factors of the number
$$
N_k:=3^{2^k}-1.
$$
Furthermore, if an odd prime $p\mid N_k$, then the order of $3$ modulo $p$ is always a power of two (as the order must be a factor of $2^k$).

On the other hand
$$
N_{k+1}=3^{2^{k+1}}-1=(3^{2^k}-1)(3^{2^k}+1)=N_k(N_k+2).
$$
Clearly $\gcd(N_k,N_k+2)=2$, so if $p$ is an odd prime factor of $N_k+2$ we can be certain that the order of $3$ modulo $p$ is exactly $2^{k+1}$. Because $N_k$ is not a power of two for any $k>1$ (Catalan's conjecture, now a theorem, implies this immediately, but is probably overkill), we see that for any $k>1$ there exists at least one prime $p$ such that
$\operatorname{ord}_p(3)=2^k$. This immediately implies that there are infinitely many primes with this property.

Here's the beginning of the list
$$
\begin{array}{c|l}
k&\text{primes with $\operatorname{ord}_p(3)=2^k$}\\
\hline
2&5\\
3&41\\
4&17,193\\
5&21523361\\
6&926510094425921\\
7&1716841910146256242328924544641\\
8&257,275201,138424618868737, 926510094425921, 3913786281514524929,153849834853910661121
\end{array}
$$

At which point my patience to wait for another factorization runs out. Surprisingly few primes actually. Probably somebody else knows more about this.

Comment: Use of Catalan's conjecture above can be replaced with the well known fact that the order of $3$ in the group $\Bbb{Z}_{2^\ell}^*$ is $2^{\ell-2}$. This means that $2^{\ell}$ is the highest power of two dividing $3^{2^{\ell-2}}-1$. But $3^{2^{\ell-2}}-1$ is clearly $>2^\ell$ whenever $\ell>3$.